# Installing Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 - throws qt.network.ssl error on terminal

Tags: qt5.5, qt-installer

I am planning to install qt 5.5.1 on my ubuntu 14.04 running on virtual machine. I have downloaded the installer from qt-io and when I try to install the setup, I notice the below warning on my terminal, and then the installer pop up.

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

Do I need to worry much about this warning ? I dont see any error of this kind when I installed qt 5.3.1 on same machine.

Is there a way to resolve this warning ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

This is the current version of openSSL on my machine.

```
openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

just install libssl-0.98 and it should work

Comment: qt 5.5.1 requires libssl-0.98 , it is a known issue you can check it on qtbug link https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42115

Comment: 0.9.8 forgot one dot sorry